# fixed table header with cross browser campatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi Friends
I  saw many examples for fixing table header with jquery, JS, CSS, plugins etc which are running correctly but none of them have cross browser compatibility.
But i want to make a fixed table header with cross browser compatibility. Is there any way to do this or not ?

Please help...

Comment: Can you be a little more clear with what it is you want to achieve? Maybe supply some HTML, CSS or link on jsfiddle?

Comment: There is no such thing as just saying "cross-browser compatibility." Define your minimum target browser/version combinations. As @Parry says, though, the primary one you need usually need to worry about is IE(and probably 6). But really, with that one you should consider whether it's truly important to offer those people an identical versus gracefully-degraded situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx) that does it.

It's from 2009, but a very cursory check with the latest browser versions turns up no obvious problems. (Though for future reference, see my comment directly on the question, above.)

Comment: How can i use this Currently I am using php.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this, but you have to write separate code for different browsers and then you have to detect via javascript which browser is requesting then according to the browser type serve the code.

In general you only need to check for Internet explorer

Comment: -1 for "In general you only need to check for Internet explorer". This is how we get all the non-standard based websites that break in all browsers but IE. You should check all supported browsers. Minimally, FireFox and Chrome.